# Proxyquire: Cannot Stub Cassandra-driver

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, cassandra, proxyquire

I am trying to mock Cassandra for unit test cases , I am using npm Cassandra-driver for connecting/querying cassandra.
for mocking the stub this is my code.

```
beforeEach(function () {
        let CassandraClient = sinon.stub();
    CassandraClient.prototype.execute = sinon.stub().returns(new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
        console.log("Inside execute method");
        fulfill(cassndaraExperimentQueryData);
    }));
    const CassandraClientWrapper = proxyquire('../../../../api/services/index.js', { 'cassandra-driver': { Client: CassandraClient } });
    console.log(typeof CassandraClientWrapper);
    CassandraClientWrapper.init();
    });
```

this is how my index.js looks

```
   const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
    module.exports = class DBServices {
    init(){
    const contactPoint = process.env['cassndraIP'] || '127.0.0.1';
    var casssandraClient = new cassandra.Client({
              contactPoints: [contactPoint]
            });
let persistentObject  = new persistent(redisMockClient, casssandraClient)
    }
    }
```

but here instead of creating the mock object it creates the object from Cassandra-driver which connect to actual DB.

Comment: are you sure your path is correct? one way could be to get the base project path in some sort of settings/initialization file, and then make sure the path is relative to that path

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring your code might allow you to stub out `cassandra-client` and remove the dependency on proxyquire.

By providing a constructor to `DBServices` and haveing the caller "inject" the dependency it should allow for easier testing:

```
    module.exports = class DBServices {
    constructor(cassandra) {
       this.cassandra = cassandra;
    }

    init(){
      const contactPoint = process.env['cassndraIP'] || '127.0.0.1';
      var casssandraClient = new this.cassandra.Client({
        contactPoints: [contactPoint]
      });
      let persistentObject  = new persistent(redisMockClient, casssandraClient)
      }
    }
```

Now your test can construct the stub, import your DBServices and create a new `DBservices` with the stub, and exercise the DBServices and make assertions on your stub!

This now requires the caller to import the actual production cassandra and make calls on it:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
let db = new DBServices(cassandra);
db.init()
```

Testing these higher level callers though could take place in integration or system tests were you can actually use the real cassandra-driver, since the `DBServices` is already unit tested.